# How do you set your Android smartphone not to switch to the web browser app each time you click on a link?

Tags: applications, firefox-for-android, hyperlinks

I'm using Firefox in my android smartphone instead of Chrome (Chrome app is not installed), but I think that it applies the same anyways. In the past when I clicked on a link (from emails, or other apps, etc.), I got a message that said that a new tab was opened in Firefox but the system didn't switch automatically to the Firefox app. I continue clicking on links and then when I was done and I opened Firefox and all the tabs were opened for me. Recently Firefox for android was updated and after the update when I click on a link the system automatically switch to Firefox. How can I set back the system so it doesn't switch to the web browser app each time I click on a link?

Regards.

Comment: In Firefox settings enable *Tab queue*.

Comment: Irfan, Where can I find that option? I went to settings but could not find it. By the way the app was updated to version 79.0.5.

Comment: 79 brings major changes. Among other things, tab queue and tab previews are also gone, at least for the moment. You need to downgrade to use the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab queue is sadly gone from the new Firefox.
There is a feature request here but it's ignored:
https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/470#issue-409774110

You can uninstall the new Firefox and then install the old version's apk from here:
https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/mozilla/firefox/firefox-68-11-0-release/